# Couchbase Nginx Plugin Module as Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, couchbase, reverse-proxy

I am using the couchbase module with Nginx and it works well if we just want to set / get / delete data in Couchbase REST way. My requirement is a bit different. I want Nginx to work as reverse proxy in case key is not found in Couchbase with normal http call. So if key is not found, I would like to forward the same request to httpd and then get the response back and store in couchbase from Nginx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile another module for it, `srcache` the generic module for sub-request caching. Here are the instructions

```
mkdir -p nginx-couchbase
cd nginx-couchbase
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.3.7.tar.gz
wget http://packages.couchbase.com/clients/c/libcouchbase-2.0.3nginx3.tar.gz
wget http://packages.couchbase.com/clients/c/nginx-couchbase-module-0.3.1.tar.gz
wget -O srcache-nginx-module-0.30.tar.gz https://github.com/openresty/srcache-nginx-module/archive/v0.30.tar.gz
for i in *.tar.gz; do tar xvf $i; done

export PREFIX=/opt/nginx-couchbase

cd libcouchbase-2.0.3nginx3
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --enable-debug --disable-plugins --disable-tests --disable-couchbasemock
make && sudo make install
cd ..

cd nginx-1.3.7
export LIBCOUCHBASE_INCLUDE=$PREFIX/include
export LIBCOUCHBASE_LIB=$PREFIX/lib
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --add-module=../nginx-couchbase-module-0.3.1 --add-module=../srcache-nginx-module-0.30
make && sudo make install
```

The commands above, will install nginx into `/opt/couchbase-nginx`, now lets put the minimal working configuration for that to cache responses of the dynamic backend:

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log  debug;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    upstream ruby {
        server localhost:9292;
    }

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            set $key $uri$args;
            srcache_fetch GET /cache key=$key;
            srcache_store PUT /cache key=$key;
            srcache_store_statuses 200 301 302;
            proxy_pass http://ruby;
        }

        location /cache {
            internal;
            set $couchbase_key $arg_key;
            set $couchbase_cmd $arg_cmd;
            set $couchbase_val $arg_val;
            couchbase_connect_timeout 6ms;
            couchbase_timeout 3ms;
            couchbase_pass localhost:8091,127.0.0.1:8091,localhost bucket=default;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I assume that you have Couchbase Server installed to `localhost:8091` and have something dynamic on port 9292, for example:

```
ruby -run -ehttpd /usr/share/doc -p9292
```

Which will serve everything from /usr/share/doc (other oneliners [here](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255)).

Now just run

```
sudo /opt/couchbase-nginx/sbin/nginx
```

Go to http://localhost:8080, browse your docs, and check that there are new keys in your couchbase cluster.